# C# .NET UDP Sockets Async for Multiple Clients

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udpclient

I have been looking around and I can't really find what I need, especially for UDP.

I'm trying to make a basic syslog server listening on port 514 (UDP).

I have been following Microsoft's guide on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx

It doesn't clearly state (or I'm blind) how to re-open the connection for more packets to be recieved.

Here is my code (basically the same from the link)

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ReceiveMessages();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            if(ex.SocketErrorCode.ToString() == "AddressAlreadyInUse")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port already in use!");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void ReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Receive a message and write it to the console.



        UdpState s = new UdpState();

        Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
        s.u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
        RecieveMoreMessages(s);
    }

    public static void RecieveMoreMessages(UdpState s)
    {
        s.u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
    }

    public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
        IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

        Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
        string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
    }
```

I have tried reiteration but I'm running into 'Running out of buffer space' error from the socket after 2 transactions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the obsolete APM pattern you need to make `ReceiveCallback` issue the next `BeginReceive` call.

Since UDP is connectionless async IO seems pointless. Probably, you should just use a synchronous receive loop:

```
while (true) {
 client.Receive(...);
 ProcessReceivedData();
}
```

Delete all that async code.

If you insist on async IO at least use `ReceiveAsync`.

Comment: If you consider it obsolete, how should I use the 'new' stuff.

Comment: By going to the documentation for those new functions and by entering them into Google. Actually, since those functions do the same thing as the old ones there should not be much trouble.

Answer (score -1):

The msdn code has a sleep which you eliminated.  You don't need the sleep, but you do need a block.  Try these changes

```
       public static void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            // Receive a message and write it to the console.



            UdpState s = new UdpState();

            Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
            s.u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
            //block
            while (true) ;
        }

        public static void RecieveMoreMessages(UdpState s)
        {
            s.u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
        }

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
            IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

            Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
            string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
            RecieveMoreMessages(ar.AsyncState);
        }​
```

Comment: `while (true) ;` this really is not the way to pause a thread because it drives the core to 100%. I also do not see what this accomplishes.

Comment: read up on a block.  A block prevents a program from exiting.  It is built into a form project, but you need to add a block to a console application.  You could add a sleep or any other method that stop the processing